# How to create a dot product version of the product function

Tags: matrix, products

I would like to create a function to matrix multiply (dot product) n matrices together, where n is large, for example

M1*M2*M3*M4*M5*...*Mn

I know there is the 'product' function that can do this for standard multiplication but I cannot seem to find a version for dot products. I have tried using a loop but this takes forever to run when n becomes large. Is there a way around this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Dot[M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, ..., Mn]`? However, when the matrices vary much in size the order of `Dot`ting should be optimized.

Comment: Also `Dot @@ MList` comes to mind where `MList` is a list of matrices.

Comment: That would work but I was hoping to automate this process. As you can imagine when n becomes quite, large manually entering all of the matrices would become tiresome so I am looking for a way to matrix multiply these matrices Mj with the index j running from 1 to n where i can input n to be any integer I need.

Comment: `Fold[Dot[#1, M[#2]] &, M[1], Range[2, n]]`?

Answer (score 3):

I found a relatively easy method that works:

```
matrixlist=Table[M[j],{j,1,n}]
Apply[Dot,matrixlist]
```

Comment: `Dot @@ Array[M, n]`

Comment: Just what Henrik Schumacher recommended [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197038/how-to-create-a-dot-product-version-of-the-product-function#comment510755_197038)